# How to close a rusqlite connection in a mutex?

Tags: rust, rusqlite

I have a rusqlite connect in a mutex

as follows:

```
struct MyStruct {
    connection: std::sync::Mutex<rusqlite::Connection>,
}
```

When I'm finished with it I want to close it, which I attempted to do as follows:

```
let lock_ro = mystruct.connection.lock().unwrap();
lock_ro.close()
.map_err(|e| e.1)
.with_context(|| format!("failed to close))?;
```

However I get this error:

> error[E0507]: cannot move out of dereference
> of `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, rusqlite::Connection>`
>
> and: ^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type
> `rusqlite::Connection`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

If I can't move it how can I close it?

Comment: `.close()` takes ownership and destroys the `Connection`, are you fine with destroying `MyStruct` as well?

Comment: No, there could be another thread waiting on the mutex, I need some way for it to know once it gets the lock that the connection is now closed. I was using a bool on MyStruct to confer this information.

Answer (score 2):

If `MyStruct` is shared between threads when you want to close it, you can store it as an `Option`:

```
struct MyStruct {
    connection: std::sync::Mutex<Option<rusqlite::Connection>>,
}
```

So then when you want to close it, you can take ownership of the value via `.take()` and then call `.close()`:

```
mystruct.connection
    .lock()
    .expect("lock should not be poisoned")
    .take()
    .expect("there should be a connection")
    .close()
    .map_err(|e| e.1)
    .with_context(|| format!("failed to close"))?;
```